# How to add iframe to sanitized tags in ruby on rails 4.2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe

I am trying to add iframe to santized tags by using

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags
```

I tried to find what tags are already allowed by using the console.

```
uraai@raiuorial:~/workspace/corse (master) $ heroku run rails c
Running rails c on ⬢ fa4... up, run.9396
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.6)
irb(main):001:0> puts helper.sanitized_allowed_tags.to_a
NoMethodError: undefined method `sanitized_allowed_tags' for #<ActionView::Base:0x007f18ea91ea60>
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/metamagic-3.1.7/lib/metamagic/view_helper.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):1
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from /app/bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Any idea how to add it without ignoring the other tags? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look on the next example:

```
module Tapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # In config/application.rb
    config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ['strong', 'em', 'a', 'br', 'iframe']
  # ...
end
```

My app called `Tapp`, I'm pretty sure you will have another name here ;)

Then in the console:

```
[retgoat@iMac-Roman ~/workspace/tapp]$ rc
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
[1] pry(main)> Tapp::Application.config.action_view[:sanitized_allowed_tags]
=> ["strong", "em", "a", "br", "iframe"]
```